# Modify arrays in form alter

Tags: 7, theming, forms

I'am having an issue which i cannot understand it , for example i have the following lines:

```
$form['field']['und'][0]['#type'] = 'select';
$form['field']['und'][1]['#type'] = 'select';
$form['field']['und'][2]['#type'] = 'select';
$form['field']['und'][3]['#type'] = 'select';
```

it works as expected , but if i try to change this hard coded method to :

```
foreach ($form['field']['und'] as $field)
            $field['#type'] = 'select';
```

it is not working anymore as expected...After a call like

```
 print render($form['field']);
```

for the first paragraph the result is good , as expected. But for the second paragraph it is not working anymore, the result is like nothing has been modified in the array. In the dsm($form) result either way the value of '#type' key is modified... I cannot understand the behavior. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like PHP documentation says:
In order to be able to directly modify array elements within the loop precede $value with &. In that case the value will be assigned by reference.

```
<?php
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
foreach ($arr as &$value) {
    $value = $value * 2;
}
// $arr is now array(2, 4, 6, 8)
unset($value); // break the reference with the last element
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: But be careful, it can be dangerous: http://www.kipras.com/blog/the-danger-of-foreach-array-as-v/66 and http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/141-References-and-foreach.html.